# Booting Ubuntu from USB, but then welcome screen stays and nothing happens

Tags: system-installation

I tried booting from the USB, it boots correctly but then the welcome screen stays and nothing happens, even after waiting for an hour.

Can anyone please suggest what I should do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that your hardware does not support the default boot options chosen by Ubuntu. This could cause the machine to hang indefinitely.

After restarting the machine, and booting from the USB stick, you should be presented with a menu like this:

[image: Live USB boot menu]

Try pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>, which will present you with common kernel options:

[image: ubunutu kernel boot options]

I suggest experimenting. For machines I have worked upon, I found that the options `acpi=off`, `noapic` and `edd=off` were required, for example.

Images taken from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions, which has further details if you require.